# How make certain datagridview column to only accept numeric value in C#

Tags: c#

The following code makes `DataGridView` `Column4` to only accept numeric value and one decimal dot `.` and it works fine for example it accepts values such as (4.50 , 3.00 , 13.60)

But the problem is: I still can save a decimal dot by itself inside the cell (Without any numbers just the decimal dot) and I do not want the cell to have only decimal dot because the sql database (money column) do not accept only decimal dot.

Any one knows how to prevent the cells in `Column4` to not accept only decimal dot but to accept values like: (4.50 , 3.00 , 13.60) ?

please help Thank you

```
 private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(AnyColumnKeyPress);
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4 ) //Desired Column
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(AnyColumnKeyPress);
            }



        }
    }

    private void AnyColumnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // allow 1 dot:


        if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }



    }
```

Comment: @Fabjan . sorry I am new to c#. can you please explain where to use your code? thank you

Comment: Kate have you solved the problem already ?

Comment: @Fabjan , no i did not. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to be:

```
private void AnyColumnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // allow 1 dot:


        if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
        {
            if ( (sender as TextBox).Text != "." ) {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: Hi. I used your code but nothing changed , still same result. I still can enter only the dot by itself. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

checked the code above and i could still enter a dot char, altered it slightly to be more readable to me.

```
if (!(char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) || char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) || e.KeyChar == '.')
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Tested and I could enter only digits.